# Woocommerce deleted and replaced my Wordpress front/page. How do I restore my original page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Whilst adding a shop section my Wordpress site, I agreed to a suggestion from Woocommerce that offered to create a new homepage, thinking it was a customisable front page for the shop page. Instead, it overwrote my front/home page completely without any warning that it would do so.

I urgently need my original home page back but I can't find it in trash or anywhere. I don't have a backup either. Woocommerce did not warn me this would ovewrite my homepage in some irreversible way.

Has anyone come across this issue before and know how to resolve it / restore the home page?

I spent a long time designing the front page and it was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you have revisions enabled you may be able to recover it using that build-in system - search the WP docs if you're not familiar with post revisions.  If you don't see the revisions metabox you may need to unhide it.